# Consume scoped service in Razor Model (Dependency Injection)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dependency-injection

I want to use a scoped service in a Razor PageModel. The registration is like:

```
services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
```

But Microsoft says don't use constructor injection on scoped services:

> When using a scoped service in a middleware, inject the service into the Invoke or InvokeAsync method. Don't inject via constructor injection because it forces the service to behave like a singleton.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes

But which option do I have to inject a scoped service in Razor outside constructor?

Comment: NOTE: *When using a scoped service in a **middleware*** That quote does not apply to `PageModel`, which can and is advised to have constructor injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When using a scoped service in a **middleware***, ...

NOTE:  *emphasis mine*

That quote refers specifically to middleware and does not apply to `PageModel`, which can, and is advised to, use constructor injection.

```
public class MyPage: PageModel {

    //ctr
    public MyPage(IOperationScoped operation) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

> The PageModel class allows separation of the logic of a page from its presentation. It defines page handlers for requests sent to the page and the data used to render the page. This separation allows:
>
> - Managing of page dependencies through **dependency injection.**
> - Unit testing

Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/)